# Mixed models (lme4) + lsmeans to estimate trend in population means

Tags: mixed-model, lsmeans

I aim to estimate one populations mean blood pressure during different years. Here is the setting:
(1) 7400 onservations; repeated measurements. Unbalanced.
(2) measurements are undertaken anually from 2001 to 2012. Eachindividual maybe measured several times.
(3) one can expect a time-bias, i.e as time progress, there will be made advances in therapy, which will lead to more efficient blood pressure lowering. These factors will not be taken into account. Deliberately.

**Aim**: estimate population mean blood pressure each year. Including confidence interval.

**Methods**: use lme4 package (linear outcome, blood pressure) to account for repeated measurements and lsmeans package to estimate the population mean each year.

Code:

```
fit <- lmer(bloodpressure ~ year + age + sex + (1 | patient_id), data=data)

'year' is the factor variable for which I'd like to obtsin the means.

lsmeans(fit, ~ year) # not tried
```

Questions
- is this method OK?
- will the covariance be respected by using lsmeans, or should I use lmerTest package which has a built in function for estimating lsmeans?
- each individual has a random slope in the call above, should I adjust it to include random effects for year also?

Thanks for any advice on this

Comment: The lsmeans package DOES use the ccorrect ovariate matrix from the object. If you look in the vignettes, you'll find some examples with models fitted with `lmer`.

Comment: Thanks @rvl. And the results appear plausible after comparing with crude figures. I'm only using a random term for individual. Id you could provide your comment as answer instead I can approve the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **lsmeans** package does produce the correct results with model objects from a number of packages, including **lme4**. If you have a fairly recent update of **lsmeans** installed, you can do `? models` and see information on what model objects are supported, and details of any special provisions.

Comment: What's the difference between lmertest, mertools and lsmeans?